# Nextjs SSR data fetching error, returning UNICODE

Tags: api, next.js, unicode, server-side-rendering, prisma

Good day everyone,
I am building a project using React Tsx, Nextjs, Prisma and Swagger.

**Problem** : part of api fetched data is returned as unicode, whereas other data in the same api is fetched with no issues. Plus, the problematic data should be an array, but returned as string unicode.

**Tests I've tried** :

1. When **yarn build and yarn start**- checked Network tab and fetches all data perfectly fine.
2. When check **localhost's swagger**- all data fetched with no issues.
3. When checked **dev domain's swagger**- all data fetched with no issues.
4. When checked **dev domain's website** - partial api fetched data is returned as string unicode instead of an array
   I've been searching for an answer or similar situations, but wasn't successful.
   Could you please help me out if you've experienced a similar issue? Or give me an idea what to look for?
   I really am lost atm :(

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproduction so that we can try to run it locally and investigate what could be the issue?